# Debug Assertion Failed. Expression Map iterator not dereferencable

Tags: c++, windows, pointers, memory-management

I'm trying to delete objects through an iterator as shown in the code below. The program seemed to run fine on ubuntu but I'm now in visual studio and it's throwing a debug assertion failed error. Expression: Map/set iterator not dereferencable.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
map<string, Booking*> bookings; // private variable

 /**
 * remove a booking from the passenger's booking map.
 * @param flightNumber string& - flight number of the booking to be removed.
 */
void Passenger::removeBooking(string& flightNumber)
{
    map<string, Booking*>::iterator it = bookings.find(flightNumber);
    bookings.erase(it);
    delete (*it).second; // <-- error occurs here
}

/**
 * add a booking to the passenger's booking map.
 * @param booking Booking& - the booking to be added.
 */
void Passenger::addBooking(Booking& booking)
{
    Booking* bookingPtr = new Booking(booking);
    bookings.insert(pair<string, Booking*>(booking.getFlightNumber(), bookingPtr));
}

/**
 * add a booking to the passenger's booking map.
 * @param flightNumber string& - flight number of the booking.
 * @param seat Seat::Type - seat type of the booking.
 * @param status Booking::Type - status of the booking.
 */
void Passenger::addBooking(string& flightNumber, Seat::Type seat, BookingStatus::Type status)
{
    Booking *bookingPtr = new Booking(flightNumber, seat, status);
    bookings.insert(pair<string, Booking*>(flightNumber, bookingPtr));
}
```

Comment: Where and how `passengerList` is declared in your class?

Comment: It's just a private variable. `vector<Passenger*> passengerList`

Comment: Are you sure the error is generated where you say it is? The iterator is being dereferenced just two lines above and no error was generated.

Comment: Most probably a problem with dangling pointers or copying/rule of three issues elsewhere in your code. You should try to reduce the problem to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post this.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm sure your correct. I'm rather strongly convinced that is *not* where the error is being reported, especially considering the specific error is for a map/set and there is none there (its a vector). I'm rather curious what is in the `Passenger` class though, because I've a feeling it has a map or set as a member variable, and the destructor of `Passenger` is the culprit.

Comment: @MarkRansom yes you were right. I managed to track down the error to the code above. The error occurs when I try to delete the booking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, now that the code has *completely* changed from what was originally posted...

The error is easy to spot. You're erasing the element from the `map` which invalidates the iterator, then you're trying to use that iterator. You should make a temporary copy of the pointer you need to `delete` before you erase the iterator, or just rearrange and do the `delete` first.

Also as suggested in the comments, you need to make sure that the iterator returned by `find` is valid, i.e. not equal to `end()`.

```
map<string, Booking*>::iterator it = bookings.find(flightNumber);
if (it != bookings.end())
{
    Booking* temp = it->second;
    bookings.erase(it);
    delete temp;
}
```

or

```
map<string, Booking*>::iterator it = bookings.find(flightNumber);
if (it != bookings.end())
{
    delete it->second;
    bookings.erase(it);
}
```

Comment: Should probably also make sure `find` actually found something.  Dereferencing `end` could cause the same error.